# How to compare two tables and skip matches?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have the table called **users**.

In this table the internal number that each employee has, their name and their departure time are stored:

| num_employee | name | departure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | John | 13:00 |
| 1002 | Lucia | 14:00 |

I have the table called **records**.

In this table, the records of the date and time in which each employee left his workplace are kept:

| num_employee | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2022-02-01 13:01:00 |
| 1002 | 2022-02-01 14:01:00 |
| 1001 | 2022-02-02 12:30:00 |
| 1002 | 2022-02-02 13:56:00 |

I have the table called **passes**.

This table records the passes that were granted to employees so that they could leave their workplace before their official departure time:

| num_employee | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2022-02-02 |

I worked on the following query to display all the times an employee left their workplace before their check-out time in a specific month (February):

```
SELECT r.num_employee,
       u.name,
       DAY(r.date) AS day,
       CAST(r.date AS time) AS time
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN(SELECT num_employee, date FROM records) r ON r.num_employee = u.num_employee
WHERE date BETWEEN '2022-02-01' AND '2022-02-28'
GROUP BY num_employee, DATE(date)
HAVING time < SUBTIME(u.departure,'0:01')
```

This query displays the employee number, their name and the day in February on which an employee retired early. The result obtained is the following:

| num_employee | name | day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | John | 2 |
| 1002 | Lucia | 2 |

I also have the following query to display the passes that were granted in the month of February:

```
SELECT p.num_employee,
       u.name,
       DAY(p.date) AS day
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN(SELECT num_employee, date FROM passes) p ON p.num_employee = u.num_employee
WHERE date BETWEEN '2022-02-01' AND '2022-02-28'
GROUP BY num_employee, DATE(date)
```

The above query displays the following result:

| num_employee | name | day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | John | 2 |

What I'm looking for is to get the employees who left before their dismissal time and don't have a pass. Based on the example above, John is the only one with a pass, so Lucia is the one who should appear as a result of those who left early without having a pass. The desired result should display as follows:

| num_employee | name | day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1002 | Lucia | 2 |

How could I get such a result? I am working with MariaDB in phpMyAdmin with a version that does not support CTE.

Comment: `query to display all the times an employee left their workplace before their check-out time in a specific month` I don't see how that sql determine a user left early. Did you post the right query? Also the `date`  column reference is ambiguous. Which table does it refer to?

Comment: @SOS, you're right. I forgot one line. I updated my question.

Comment: Which table is `date` from? In the sample it exists in both. ( I assume the columns aren't named "date" and "time" in the real table since those are reserved words :)

Comment: @SOS, ```date``` in the query I want to get comes from **records**

Comment: Okay. BTW,  by using a comparison on `date` in the WHERE clause the JOIN gets implicitly converted to an INNER JOIN. I think that's what you want anyway here, but just fyi

Answer (score 1):

*Dislaimer, I haven't used MariaDb much*. Ultimately, all you should need is an extra OUTER JOIN to `passes` on the employee number and date. Then exclude any rows *with* a matching pass record, i.e. `WHERE p.date IS NULL`. Without all the grouping and other filters, the base query would look like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users u
        INNER JOIN records r ON r.num_employee = u.num_employee
        LEFT JOIN passes p ON p.num_employee = u.num_employee 
             AND p.date = DATE(r.Date)
WHERE  p.date IS NULL
```

Which yields this result:

> ```
> num_employee | name  | departure | num_employee | date                | num_employee | date
> -----------: | :---- | :-------- | -----------: | :------------------ | -----------: | :---
>         1001 | John  | 13:00:00  |         1001 | 2022-02-01 13:01:00 |         null | null
>         1002 | Lucia | 14:00:00  |         1002 | 2022-02-01 14:01:00 |         null | null
>         1002 | Lucia | 14:00:00  |         1002 | 2022-02-02 13:56:00 |         null | null
> ```

Then just add back the grouping and date filters:

```
SELECT r.num_employee,
       u.name,
       u.departure,
       DAY(r.date) AS day,
       CAST(r.date AS time) AS time
FROM users u
        INNER JOIN records r ON r.num_employee = u.num_employee
        LEFT JOIN passes p ON p.num_employee = u.num_employee 
             AND p.date = DATE(r.Date)
WHERE r.date >= '2022-02-01' 
AND   r.date < '2022-03-01'
AND   p.date IS NULL
GROUP BY r.num_employee, DATE(r.date)
HAVING time < SUBTIME(departure,'0:01')
```

**Results:**

> ```
> num_employee | name  | departure | day | time    
> -----------: | :---- | :-------- | --: | :-------
>         1002 | Lucia | 14:00:00  |   2 | 13:56:00
> ```

A few notes about the original query:

> **LEFT** JOIN(SELECT num_employee, date FROM records) r ON r.num_employee = u.num_employee
> WHERE **date BETWEEN '2022-02-01' AND '2022-02-28'**

In this case you don't really need an OUTER JOIN, but be aware that filtering on `records.date` in the WHERE clause will implicitly convert the JOIN into an INNER JOIN. Just something to be aware of ...

> WHERE date BETWEEN '2022-02-01' AND '2022-02-28'

Because `date` contains both a date and time, that clause will end up excluding most of the entries on Feb 28, 2022. Instead, use the comparison `where date >= StartDateAtMidnight and < EndDateAtMidnight + 1 Day`.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=990998e294c783e156b09cdec1281826)*

Comment: It works, but it's a very slow query. For me, it takes almost two minutes to display the results. Do you know any way to optimize it?

Comment: (Edit) Seeing the actual table structure and values would help here. 1) Post the SHOW COLUMNS output for all 3 tables 2) What are the indexes on the tables? 3) Are the data samples posted accurate or were they formatted for readability? Because `User.Departure` appears to store a time value only. Could you update the sample data to show the real date/time values? 4) Run an EXPLAIN on the query. I suspect using a `having` clause and/or  having to convert between date, datetime and time types for the comparisons is what's slowing things down.